# Spring extending PagingAndSortingRepository sorting order

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm currently implementing an `CustomRepository` which extends Spring `PagingAndSortingRepository` because I need sorting functionality by `String name` within this repository.

Everything work as desired I have a generated rest repository under:
`http://localhost:8080/app/customrepository{?page,size,sort}`

When I want to sort it via url e.g.:
`http://localhost:8080/app/customrepository?sort=name,asc`
it is getting sorted, but in case sensitive order. The problem is I need case unsensitive sorting. Is there a way to achieve that without custom processors?

I used following URL to gain knowledge:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource

Comment: I am pretty sure that Spring Data performs the sorting on the database level and just provides us with a convenient API. Depending on the DB you are using there may be different collation settings, for example on MSSQL Server this would yeld such results: CS AI (Case Sensitive Accent Insensitive).

Comment: Oracle 10g. It does sort but in case senaitive way. I want to sort in case unsensitive way

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not support mostly due to the fact the the component translating the sorting HTTP request parameters only considers property name and direction. I've filed [DATACMNS-658](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-658) for you to keep track of this requirement.

As a workaround you could write an aspect that intercepts calls to the query methods that you want to enforce case-ignored sorting to be applied:

```
@Aspect
static class SortManipulatingAspect {

  /**
   * Intercept all calls to repositories. Might wanna be more specific in the
   * pointcut to maker sure you don't unnecessarily intercept methods without
   * a Sort.
   */
  @Around("execution(public * org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.*(..))")
  public Object enableIgnoreCaseSorting(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    return joinPoint.proceed(
      Arrays.stream(joinPoint.getArgs()).map(sortWithIgnoreCase()).toArray()
    );
  }

  private static Function<Object, Object> sortWithIgnoreCase() {

    return (arg) -> arg instanceof Sort ? new Sort(
      toOrderStream((Sort) arg).
      // Insert filter here to be selective about which orders to actually
      // activate ignore-case on.
      map(order -> order.ignoreCase()).//
      collect(Collectors.toList())) : arg;
    }

  private static Stream<Order> toOrderStream(Sort sort) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(sort.spliterator(), false);
  }
}
```

If you declare make this class a Spring bean (by pick-up through component scanning or explicit registration) all `Sort` instances will get ignore-case being activated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, in both cases, you need to extend the Spring default behavior

1- Extending spring base class for repository interfaces (https://medium.com/@ghahremani/extending-default-spring-data-repository-methods-patch-example-a23c07c35bf9)

2- or extending the Pageable handler (https://medium.com/@ghahremani/pageable-and-sort-in-webflux-c6f6c598537a), Note: this is for reactive programming but the concept is same, you will understand how you need to extend your Pageable handler.